# Variable Issues

Tags: java, variables

So this project requires me to "make up" a secret agent, and by doing this by randomized events- like birthday, gender, name, city etc... I've been having trouble with my birthday portion of this code..and I think I have to make a temporary variable but I'm not sure... and I read through this in a linear fashion and it looks okay from int->string with a boolean in there. Any help??

```
public static Agent GetRandomAgent()
{
    Agent randomAgent = new Agent();

    WordList maleName = new WordList("MaleNames.txt");
    WordList femaleName = new WordList("FemaleNames.txt");
    WordList cityBorn = new WordList("Cities.txt");
    WordList cityNow = new WordList ("Cities.txt");
    WordList major = new WordList ("Majors.txt");

    //Setter methods
    //Sets the gender of the agent generated 


    double setGender = (Math.random()); 

    Random r = new Random();

    if(Math.random()*100 > 50)
    {
        randomAgent.gender = "female";
    }
    else //if not female, then male
    {
        randomAgent.gender = "male";
    }

    public String setBirthday()
    //randomAgent.birthday = new String getBirthday; 
    {
        int birthdayYear = 1900 + (int)(Math.random() * ((2012 - 1900) + 1));
        int birthdayMonth = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1));

        switch(birthdayMonth) {
        //set for 30-day months: April(4), June(6), September(9), November(11)
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            birthdayDay = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 1) + 1));
            break;

        case 2:
            if (isLeapYear(birthdayYear)) {
              birthdayDay = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((29 - 1) + 1));
            } else {
              birthdayDay = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((28 - 1) + 1));
            }
            break;

        //Set for 31-day months: January(1), March(3), May(5), July(7), August(8), October(10), December(12)
          default:
            birthdayDay = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((31 - 1) + 1));
          break;
        }

        //Convert the random integers back into Strings (easier to use)
        String year = Integer.toString(birthdayYear);
        String month = Integer.toString(birthdayMonth);
        String day = Integer.toString(birthdayDay);

        //Account to make sure there is a zero before the date (clarity)
        if (birthdayMonth < 10) {
            month = "0" + birthdayMonth;
        }

        if (birthdayDay < 10) {
            day = "0" + birthdayDay;
        }

        String suffix; 
        if ((day.equals("01") || (day.equals("21") || (day.equals("31")))))
        {
            suffix = "st";
        }

        if ((day.equals("02") || (day.equals("22"))))
        {
            suffix = "nd";
        }

        if (day == "03" || day == "23")
        {
                    suffix = "rd";
        }
        else
        { 
            suffix = "th";
        }
        return this.birthday = (day + suffix + " " + month + " of " + year); 
      }

      public static boolean isLeapYear;
      int year; 
      {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        rightNow.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        int numberOfDays = rightNow.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        if (numberOfDays > 365) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: oh oh and the only problem so far, is that the method header is wrong ....

Comment: Better you add java tag

Comment: and also I make the random agent.. using randomAgent, ..so i think somewhere in there i need to have a variable randomAgent.birthday... or this.birthday..something like this

Comment: What does "having trouble" mean?  Is there a specific compiler error you are getting?

Comment: Tell us what the problem is specifically instead of expecting us to also figure that out.

Comment: yes! well String is underlined , as is the ()... and it says :
Syntax error on token "String", @ expected

Comment: "The method header is wrong": The first thing I'd do is take a look at your method signature for `setBirthday()` and use that to fix `isLeapYear`

Comment: @Lukas But _which_ String? Under year? month? The method signature for setBirthday()?

Comment: Dont compare String with `==`, use [`String#equals()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Chris, what do you mean by that? Should it not be a string? or should i change the title? I'm unsure...

Comment: The method signature!

Comment: The method signature for `isLeapYear` should probably be `public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {`.

Comment: In that case, @Lukas, there's more to your *.java file than displayed. Creating a class and adding those two methods reveal no issues with the `setBirthday()` method signature (although there are other issues)

Comment: does it help maybe if i show you this as an example? this part of the code works! it's also under a constructor :
i'll post it under Agent constructor (or a new question) :)

Comment: If the underline is shown for "String" in the setBirthday declaration then just add whatever is above it to the code in the OP. It sounds like there is a missing brace or something like that. In cases like that the syntax error will "trickle down" to whatever comes after.

Comment: Sorry chris, I can only post every 20 minutes, so I'll fiddle around with it for awhile ..and Radiodef I will definitely have a look at that!

Comment: And please don't post a new question! You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20478699/edit) your question to add additional information, however.

Comment: ^ Ah right, forgot about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few things wrong with the code:

1. The reason you were getting an error with the `setBirthday()` method signature was because `GetRandomAgent()` hadn't been closed yet. Please note the ending brace after setting `randomAgent.birthday`.
2. `birthdayDay` was not initialized in `setBirthday()`.
3. The method signature for `isLeapYear(int)` was incorrect.
4. As Smit said, you need to compare Strings with `.equals()` instead of `==`.

Keeping all that in mind...

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;

public class Agent
{

    String gender;
    String birthday;

    public static Agent GetRandomAgent()
    {
        Agent randomAgent = new Agent();

        WordList maleName = new WordList("MaleNames.txt");
        WordList femaleName = new WordList("FemaleNames.txt");
        WordList cityBorn = new WordList("Cities.txt");
        WordList cityNow = new WordList("Cities.txt");
        WordList major = new WordList("Majors.txt");

        //Setter methods
        //Sets the gender of the agent generated 
        double setGender = (Math.random());

        Random r = new Random();

        if(Math.random() * 100 > 50)
        {
            randomAgent.gender = "female";
        }
        else //if not female, then male
        {
            randomAgent.gender = "male";
        }
        randomAgent.birthday = randomAgent.setBirthday();
    }

    public String setBirthday()
    {
        int birthdayYear = 1900 + (int) (Math.random() * ((2012 - 1900) + 1));
        int birthdayMonth = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((12 - 1) + 1));
        int birthdayDay;
        switch(birthdayMonth)
        {
            //set for 30-day months: April(4), June(6), September(9), November(11)
            case 4:
            case 6:
            case 9:
            case 11:
                birthdayDay = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((30 - 1) + 1));
                break;

            case 2:
                if(isLeapYear(birthdayYear))
                {
                    birthdayDay = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((29 - 1) + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    birthdayDay = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((28 - 1) + 1));
                }
                break;

            //Set for 31-day months: January(1), March(3), May(5), July(7), August(8), October(10), December(12)
            default:
                birthdayDay = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((31 - 1) + 1));
                break;
        }

        //Convert the random integers back into Strings (easier to use)
        String year = Integer.toString(birthdayYear);
        String month = Integer.toString(birthdayMonth);
        String day = Integer.toString(birthdayDay);

        //Account to make sure there is a zero before the date (clarity)
        if(birthdayMonth < 10)
        {
            month = "0" + birthdayMonth;
        }

        if(birthdayDay < 10)
        {
            day = "0" + birthdayDay;
        }

        String suffix;
        if((day.equals("01") || (day.equals("21") || (day.equals("31")))))
        {
            suffix = "st";
        }

        if((day.equals("02") || (day.equals("22"))))
        {
            suffix = "nd";
        }

        if(day.equals("03") || day.equals("23"))
        {
            suffix = "rd";
        }
        else
        {
            suffix = "th";
        }
        return this.birthday = (day + suffix + " " + month + " of " + year);
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year)
    {
        Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        rightNow.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        int numberOfDays = rightNow.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

        if(numberOfDays > 365)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```